# Prevent Typing a Line Break in textarea Input With onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace..."

Tags: php, html, input, textarea, onkeyup

I don't want users to type some characters in my textarea input.
I use a global variable (php): `

```
$preventedInputCharacters = '=:;?/$*<>|\[\]\'';
```

And use it in textarea input (Sorry for the escaping backslashes, it is from a php string.):

```
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/['.$preventedInputCharacters.']/g, \'\')"
```

The problem is, when user uses line break (enter key), it harms my code so I want to disable it too.

Where and how should I modify to add "line break" to my prevented input characters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding \n is the answer:

```
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/['.$preventedInputCharacters.'\n]/g, \'\')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done it by calling jquery event keycode which will prevent the enter key function

```js
$('#textarea').keypress(function(event){
  var key_code = event.keyCode;
  if(key_code==13){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this method prevent line breaks from a copied text?

Comment: no it won't it will prevent only when the user manually add line break into the field but using regex method we can prevent here is a sample                          
someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");